# New to React and I cannot get the info that I want to come into the modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

This is my first React project that I am trying to complete and I would like for the modal to open and have the artist's name and bio show up in that modal. I have got it to the point that the modal will open and close but I cannot figure out how to get the info from my artist's request to come into the modal so I can access the information from my app.js which I am using for my index page.

This is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
// import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
// import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "./modal";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Artist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    artists: [],
    modal: false,
  };
  selectModal = (info) => {
    this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal }); // true/false toggle
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/artists").then((res) => {
      const artists = res.data;
      this.setState({ artists });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Horrorcore Bible</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
              {/* <Nav className="me-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
                <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Divider />
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </Nav>
              <Nav>
                <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
                  Dank memes
                </Nav.Link>
              </Nav> */}
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>

        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#BA1313" }}>
          <Row xs={1} md={3} className="g-4">
            {this.state.artists
              .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
              .map((artist) => (
                <Col>
                  <Card className="text-center" border="dark" style={{ width: "27.95rem", backgroundColor: "black" }}>
                    <Card.Img
                      variant="top"
                      src={artist.image}
                      alt="artist"
                      className="image"
                      style={{ height: 400, width: 445 }}
                    />
                    <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Title style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>{artist.name}</Card.Title>

                      <Modal displayModal={this.state.modal} closeModal={this.handleClose} More Info />
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              ))}
          </Row>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

// export default Artist;
```

This is the modal

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import { Artists } from "./App.js";

class Example extends React.Component {
  function Artist() {
  render() {
    const artists = this.props.artists;
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleShow}>
          More Info
        </Button>

        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{this.artists.name}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            {/* <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button> */}
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}
}

export default Example;
```

I have looked into redux and I have looked into functional components and I do not understand how to get it across to the modal. Any links or tutorials that break it down step by step would be greatly appreciated to help get me on track.

Comment: i see that you get the artists data in the modal by props but you didnt pass it  .         
 
`const artists = this.props.artists; `


  <Modal displayModal={this.state.modal} closeModal={this.handleClose} **artist={artist}** />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be parsing the artist data into your `<Modal>` component via props

```
<Modal displayModal={this.state.modal} closeModal={this.handleClose} More Info />
```

should be

```
<Modal artists={artist} displayModal={this.state.modal} closeModal={this.handleClose} More Info />
```

and now you will be able to access the artist data via `this.props.artists` within the `<Modal/>` component.

Just to add, I think the naming convention of your `<Artist>` component could be confusing. I'd be more inclined to call it something along the lines of `<ArtistList>` as the singular component fetches data from an API about multiple different artists. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I got that fixed now I just have to figure out the useState issue that I am having and I should be on the right track.

Comment: @PhilipJobe I was going to say I think I spotted a problem with the useState but I'm not 100% sure as I don't use class components in react and I'm relatively new. have you tried `this.setState((prevState) => {...prevState})` spread operator where you are changing your state throughout your application?

Comment: Yeah this is my first react project outside of a few tutorials that I have done so it is all a lot of trial and error it keeps telling me that I need to put it into a react function so I am trying to get that figured out.

Comment: Finally got it figured out along with your answer I had to set it in a function like this function Example(props) {
  const artists = props.artists;
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

Comment: @PhilipJobe cool! Eventually react will just click and the key concepts seem self explanatory but it definitely took me a little while of trial and error as well. I’d recommend making a project with functional components and hooks rather than classes as classes are basically only used for legacy code and old devs who have used it and don’t want to make the switch nowadays to my knowledge but the concepts will still be helpful to know :)